# Hair Particles Not Working

Tags: modeling, particles, hair

[image]

[image]

i'm trying to add hair onto this model I got and for some reason when I use hair lab to create the hair no matter what I change the particles to it is not showing up like normal... It ends up looking very thin and practically not there. This doesn't make sense because when I add a cube and create hair the particles show up normally. Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: Look into manual weight painting and vertex groups.